Finding the radius of a helix shaped function
I stumbled upon a problem in my textbook where I'm supposed to find the radius of the cylinder which a helix shaped graph travels around. The problem goes as follows:
"A particle travels around a helix curve. After 10 seconds it has rotated 4 times around the center line of the helix curve, and moved 5 meters in the z-direction. The length of the curve that the particle has moved along is 75 meter. What is the radius of the imagined cylinder which the particle moves around?"
I've tried finding the vector function that describes the particle's movement, and I've come up with the expression $$\overrightarrow{r}(t)=[R\cdot cos(\frac{4\pi}{5}t), R\cdot sin(\frac{4\pi}{5}t),\frac{1}{2}t]$$
where the sine and cosine arguments takes into account that after 10 seconds the particle has "spun around" 4 times, and the z-coordinate of the function will make sure that the particle has traveled 5 meters in the positive z-direction in the same time span.
My approach to finding the value of R has been to try to integrate the velocity function of the particle and solving the equation I get when I set this to equal 75, but I've never done this for vector functions before and I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Think simple: Cut the cylinder along axis direction. The helix is a line in the euclidean flat strip, left and right boundary identified.
Complete the flat euclidean plane with copies, the infinite cover of the circular cylinder.
The cylinder is intrinsically flat by the fact, that the metrics is constant in cylinder coordinates $(z,\phi).$

I like the idea of cutting the cylinder along axis direction, but I don't understand the rest of your reasoning I'm afraid. How do I calculate the length of the helix, which is now found on the flat strip?

Imagine the helix with basis circle and vertical line from the end as wet color and roll it on paper. In the image on the plane you find a rectangular triangle with basis $a=4*2 \pi r$, hight $b=5$ and long side $c=75. Pythogoras says $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

Now I understand and I really like this solution! I also found another way of solving it, by finding the velocity vector and seeing that the particle moves with a constant velocity where the radius was part of the expression of the constant velocity. From there I integrated from t = 0 to t = 10 and solved for the radius.
